# How to add an alertcondition for this TradingView indicator

Tags: pine-script

I have a TradingView indicator in Pine Script, which I use for my trading strategy, but it doesn't have alerts in its code, and as a result, I miss some trading opportunities.

This indicator is a simple moving average SMA of the previous n period's highs or lows.

The indicator tracks both curves (of the highs and the lows). The close of the bar defines which of the two gets plotted.

I want to add a BUY alert when the price crosses the red line and a SELL alert when the price crosses the green line, but I don't have any experience in Pine Script.

I am attaching below the indicator's code and the screenshots. I would appreciate any help in adding these alerts.

```
//@version=2
study("My Gann Hi/Lo", overlay=true)
HPeriod= input(13,"HIGH Period")
LPeriod= input(21,"LOW Period")
HLd= iff(close>nz(sma(high,HPeriod))[1],1,iff(close<nz(sma(low,LPeriod))[1],-1,0))
HLv= valuewhen(HLd!=0,HLd,0)
Hi= HLv==-1 ? sma(high,HPeriod) : na
Lo= HLv==1 ? sma(low,LPeriod) : na
plot(Hi ? Hi : na, linewidth=2, style=linebr, color=red)
plot(Lo ? Lo : na, linewidth=2, style=linebr, color=lime)
```

BUY signal:

[image: BUY signal]

Sell signal:

[image: Sell signal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("My Gann Hi/Lo", overlay=true)
HPeriod= input(13, "HIGH Period")
LPeriod= input(21, "LOW Period")

sma_high = sma(high, HPeriod)
sma_low = sma(low, LPeriod)

HLd = iff(close > nz(sma_high)[1], 1, iff(close < nz(sma_low)[1], -1, 0))

HLv = valuewhen(HLd != 0, HLd, 0)
Hi = HLv == -1 ? sma_high : na
Lo = HLv == 1 ? sma_low : na
plot(Hi ? Hi : na, linewidth = 2, style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.red)
plot(Lo ? Lo : na, linewidth = 2, style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.lime)

longCond = HLv == 1 and HLv[1] == -1
shortCond = HLv == -1 and HLv[1] == 1

plotshape(longCond, location = location.belowbar, style = shape.triangleup, size = size.tiny, color = color.lime, title = "Long")
plotshape(shortCond, location = location.abovebar, style = shape.triangledown, size = size.tiny, color = color.red, title = "Short")

alertcondition(condition = longCond, title = "Long", message = "Gann Hi/Lo Long")
alertcondition(condition = shortCond, title = "Short", message = "Gann Hi/Lo Short")
```

Comment: Thank you very much @rumpypumpydumpy for your help. It is working!